# Battery ran out of charge suddenly and won't charge

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power, dell-inspiron

I've dell inspiron 5547 laptop and it was working fine till last night i used it. I didn't shut it down as I usually do and just closed the lid to let it go to hibernate or sleep mode, battery was fully charged then. Now, at work I pressed the power button but it did nothing, i then plugged in the charger and charging indicator turned on then switched off again, I pressed the power button again while AC adapter was plugged in, laptop booted but charging indicator started to blink in red, and it's currently doing the same as i'm typing. I checked my battery status using battery info viewer and results are as follow.
[image]

as it can be seen that battery is pretty healthy (65%) but it's not charging....
further in bios it says "this battery has experience permanent failure and needs to be replaced" 
i'm unable to understand this. any help would be much appreciated

Comment: The battery capacity is severely degraded and chances are one of the cells has now died. Replace it.

Comment: is it supposed to have somewhere near the designated capacity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The battery capacity is severely degraded and chances are one of the cells has now died. The battery is not charging at all and its "current capacity" is at "0.0%"

A healthy or new battery should be at or near it's "design capacity". One that is at about 60% capacity has either had a hard life, is very old or both. Batteries loose capacity over time and need to be replaced. As they age their chances of critical or catastrophic failure do increase as there are important chemical changes going on both during the charge/discharge cycles as well as over the life of the battery. Whiskers of metal can form in the battery puncturing layers separating internal parts, or films can form on contacts blocking the flow of electrons.

If an actual cell in the battery has failed and discharged itself then it it potentially hazardous and needs to be disposed of per your manufacturer guidelines.

Your BIOS message is also telling you exactly the same: that it is old, has failed, and needs replacement.

Replace it.

There is a very small chance that it could be a fault in your charger circuitry in your laptop, but battery failure due to age is far more likely.

Comment: thank you for this detailed answer, i'd replace battery asap

Comment: but the failure was sudden, windows never gave me a warning before about battery, and it still could hold up to 5 hours in stand by and even more if on battery saving mode.

Comment: @HassanZia sadly that is how many failures happen. The process of a whisker forming within the battery is  slow one to begin with until it reaches a critical point where it suddenly accelerates or a heating/cooling cycle causes it to puncture an area and shorting out. Many failures don't have an obvious build up phase that you would or could notice, all you know is that one day it works and the next it doesn't and the only thing you can do is work out exactly why it failed. It is entirely possible that you did everything right and the failure was just destined to happen due to chemistry.